# Array(n) has wrong length on production in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to create an array of some specific length in TypeScript, but anytime I run my app in production mode (aka the minified version), the generated array length is off by one. To be concrete: when I run

```js
console.log(Array(3));
```

in dev mode, I get `(3) [empty x 3]`, but after building and running the generated file, I get `(2) [empty x 2]`.

I am running a Next.js app (version 12.2.0) with the standard build and start commands (`next dev`, `next build` and `next start`).

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

### Minimal steps to reproduction

1. run `npx create-next-app@latest` in an empty directory with default values
2. in `/pages/index.js`, add `console.log(new Array(3))` before the return statement
3. run `yarn dev` for output `(3) [empty x 3]` on localhost:3000
4. run `yarn build && yarn start` for output `(2) [empty x 2]` on localhost:3000

Comment: Does this happen if you do: const array = []; array.length = 3; console.log(array.length)

Comment: Nope, array = []; array.length = 3; works as expected

Comment: Try logging the array itself to the console, what value is it missing?

Comment: not sure what you mean, as I said, the approach you posted works fine and the one I described misses one "empty"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems related to [SWC Minification](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#minification), which transforms `Array(3)` into `[,,]` (running `console.log([,,])` outputs `(2) [empty x 2]`).

There's an on-going [SWC minify feedback discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/30237) to report these kind of issues.

---

You can either disable `swcMinify` in the `next.config.js` altogether.

```js
module.exports = {
    swcMinify: false
}
```

Or, keep `swcMinify` enabled but use something like the following until this gets fixed.

```js
Array.from({ length: 3 })
```